# Transaction shows up in blockchain.info but not in Electrum wallet

Tags: electrum

I sent a test transaction earlier today. It shows up in Blockchain.info but not in the Electrum wallet.

There are more than 20 confirmations already.

Electrum version: 2.6.4

Why is the transaction not showing up and how can I fix this?

Comment: You can help the site by marking answers as accepted if they are correct and address the question so that the question does not remain as "unanswered".

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem has been resolved. Seemingly it may have been caused by Electrum being too old in terms of version number. A simple update using the website instructions appears to have solved the issue and I can now see the balance. New version number: 2.9.3

Comment: I have version 3.0.3 same thing, some transactions shows on blockchain.info but not in electrum. over 40 confirmations.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a GAP issue.
Blockchain.info checks the 21st empty wallet, and Electrum checks only 20th.
so, if you got money on 21st, Blockchain.info shows it. and all the latest.

fix was: 1) sending money to the empty 19th wallet 2) export private keys for resync.